# Равноправные\равновозможные ударения.

Tags: орфоэпия

Доброго времени суток!
В спектакле Евгения Гришковца "Одновременно" прозвучала фраза:
"Спектакль, который вы увидите, называться "Одновре́менно" или "Одновреме́нно". Дело в том, что в орфоэпическом словаре русского языка указано, что оба варианта употребления ударения в этом слове как равноправны, так и равновозможны".
С учетом определений терминов "равноправность" и "равновероятность"(точнее, не определение, а понимания смысла данного термина, так как понятие "равновероятность", как известно из курса тервера, является неопределяемым понятием), данная фраза звучит тавтологично.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли различие между "равноправные ударения" или "равновозможные ударения" и если есть, то в чем? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Понятия равноправность и равновозможность синонимичны, но не абсолютно тождественны.

Разные теории имеют равные права на существование, но не равные возможности сбыться.Значит, они равноправны, но не равновозможны.

А вот оба варианта употребления ударения в  слове одновременно как равноправны, так и равновозможны", в отличие от равновозможного, но неравноправного ударения слов повторИт – повтОрит, позвонИт – позвОнит, пОнял – понЯл - литературный и просторечный варианты;вьЮга – вьюгА, хОлодно – холоднО - литературный и диалектный и т.д.

Так что фраза вполне корректна.

Answer (score 0):

Вы явно запутали вопрос тем, что хотите понять разницу на основе одного единственного случая использования этих слов. 
Понятно, что права и возможности вещи принципиально разные. Думаю, что объяснять эту разницу не требуется. 
А вот что касается употребления в конкретной фразе, то тут только автор фразу может сказать, что имелось в виду. Скорее всего в обоих случаях имеет место несколько вольное понимание.
Равноправные - одинаково допустимые с точки зрения нормативности, в данном случае - орфоэпической.
Равновозможные - означающие одно и то же (вообще или только в данном контексте).